# Flutter TabController - push screens inside of any particular tabitem

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a TabController in flutter which has 4 TabItems. How to push screens inside on any particular tab item with back navigation? instead of opening a new screen which covers the full screen and hides the Tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some research,  i have achieved this with Cupertino Widgets. Using [CupertinoTabScaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html) and [CupertinoTabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html) this can be done.